# WebView tel: open chooser telephone or sms

Tags: java, android, webview, sms, telephony

In my shouldOverrideUrlLoading of my WebView I do the following to have some action when a tel: link is clicked:

```
Intent tel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity( tel );
```

My problem is that it only starts the telephone app (which seems to be the normal behaviour regarding tel: links). I want something like an intent chooser where I can select whether I want to send an sms or do a phone call. Is this possible with a tel: link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DialogFragment with 2 options and let the user decide what to do.